# luabind with std::vector::at returns 'Trying to use unregistered class'

Tags: c++11, lua, luabind

I'm trying to use luabind with the std::vector.  I'm using gcc 4.8.1 with c++11.  The conversion code is shown below

```
template <typename T>
void luabindVector(lua_State* S, std::string tname) {
module(S)[class_<std::vector<T> >(tname.c_str()).def(constructor<>()).def(
        "pushBack",
        static_cast<void (std::vector<T>::*)(
                const T&)>(&std::vector<T>::push_back)).
                def("at",(T& (std::vector<T>::*)(size_t))(&std::vector<T>::at)).
                def("resize",static_cast<void (std::vector<T>::*)(size_t)>(&std::vector<T>::resize)).
                def("size",&std::vector<T>::size).
                def("assign",static_cast<void (std::vector<T>::*)(size_t, const T&)>(&std::vector<T>::assign))];
}
```

with the following invocations

```
luabindVector<double>(L,"vectorDouble");
```

In Lua I have the commands

```
tans = vectorDouble()
tans:resize(3)
a=tans:at(1)
```

which produces the error std::runtime_error: 'Trying to use unregistered class' with error 2

Note that the push_back, resize, size and assign all work properly, but the program fails on the call to tans:at(1).  It's not clear from the documentation how I'm supposed to do this correctly.  Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?